# jQuery code keeps running after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an page element after `header` element will be out ofthe viewport. To achieve this, I created simple JS:

```
var scrollHeight = $(document).scrollTop(),
    headerHeight = $('.big-header').outerHeight(true),
    setHead = 0;

    console.log(scrollHeight +' / '+ headerHeight);

if(scrollHeight >= headerHeight) {
    if(setHead == 0) {
        alert(setHead);
        setHead = 1;
    }
}
```

My problem is, `alert(setHead)` is running constantly. There's propably some minor thing I forgot, but I can't seem to get it done.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9P36u/).

Comment: your code is inside $(window).scroll(), so it executes almost for each pixel scrolled ... it is normal, i do not understand the issue

Comment: also for each pixel scrolled you set setHead  to 0 and the ask it it is 0.. of course it is 0 if you set it each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `sethead` out of the scroll function,

```
var setHead = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).scrollTop(),
        headerHeight = $('.big-header').outerHeight(true);


    console.log(scrollHeight + ' / ' + headerHeight);

    if (scrollHeight >= headerHeight) {
        if (setHead == 0) {
            alert(setHead);
            setHead = 1;
        }
    } else {
        setHead = 0;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9P36u/1/

Comment: Also move `headerHeight = $('.big-header').outerHeight(true);` outside. Height probably never change.

Answer (score 2):

define `var setHead = 0;` before `$(window).scroll(function()`.

In your function `setHead` is always being 0.